# Generating unique identifiers as a set based query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-partitioning

I am moving a bunch of code over from entirely cursor based to set based and generating this has been doing my head in. We create a 6 character shortcode (unique) for each company inserted into the database and I (want) to achieve this outside of a cursor.

Example of where I am at so far:

```
CREATE TABLE #customers (name VARCHAR(50), shortname VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #customers VALUES
('Michael Smith', 'Michae')
,('Michael Douglas', 'Mich_1')
,('Michael Yang', 'Mich_2')

CREATE TABLE #newcustomers (name VARCHAR(50), shortname VARCHAR(10) NULL)
INSERT INTO #newcustomers (name) VALUES
('Michael Black')
,('Michael White')

SELECT * FROM #customers
SELECT * FROM #newcustomers

DECLARE @shortname VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @iteration INT = 0

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT shortname FROM #customers WHERE shortname = @shortname)
BEGIN
    SELECT @shortname = LEFT(name, 6) FROM #newcustomers

    UPDATE #newcustomers SET shortname = @shortname

    SET @shortname = LEFT(@shortname, 4) + '_' + @iteration

    SET @iteration = @iteration + 1
END
```

Hopefully the example is sufficient in identifying where I am trying to get to, any suggestions or examples would be very helpful. My example does not work.

Comment: Just as a note, a `WHILE` will also be executed as a cursor. It's going to use the same implementation, it's just "masked" as a `WHILE`.

Comment: There's a typo at `Micahel Douglas` ...

Comment: Btw: This is a good question, especially the copy'n'pasteable test scenario is great, own effort, clear explanation... Worth the +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Your table as *mock-up*

```
CREATE TABLE #customers (ID INT IDENTITY, name VARCHAR(50), shortname VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #customers VALUES
('Michael Smith', 'Michae')
,('Michael Douglas', 'Mich_1')
,('Michael Yang', 'Mich_3')
,('Testman', 'Testma')
,('Testman1', 'Test_1');

CREATE TABLE #newcustomers (ID INT IDENTITY,name VARCHAR(50), shortname VARCHAR(10) NULL)
INSERT INTO #newcustomers (name) VALUES
('Michael Black')
,('Michael White')
,('Testman2')
,('Someone new');
```

--This CTE will combine all existing names

```
WITH AllNames AS
(
    SELECT '1_old' AS datasource,ID,name,shortname FROM #customers
    UNION ALL SELECT '2_new',ID,name,shortname FROM #newcustomers
)
```

--This CTE will use the combined list and calculate the right "index"

```
,ShortNames AS
(
    SELECT c.*
          ,A.First6
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.First6 ORDER BY datasource,ID) AS NrTotal
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY datasource,A.First6 ORDER BY datasource,ID) AS Nr
          ,CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(shortname+'      ',6,10))=1 
                THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(shortname+'      ',6,10) AS INT) ELSE 0 END AS ExistIndex
    FROM AllNames AS c
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT LEFT(name + '      ',6)) AS A(First6)
)
```

--All new with NrTotal=1 get the 6 letters as is, all other get the index

```
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN datasource='1_old' THEN shortname ELSE
        CASE WHEN datasource='2_new' AND NrTotal=1 THEN First6 
             ELSE LEFT(First6,4) + '_' + CAST(Nr + (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(x.ExistIndex),1)
                                                      FROM ShortNames AS x 
                                                      WHERE x.First6=ShortNames.First6) AS VARCHAR(5)) 
        END
       END
FROM ShortNames

GO
DROP TABLE #customers;
DROP TABLE #newcustomers;
```

The result

```
+------------+----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+----+------------+--------------------+
| datasource | ID | name            | shortname | First6 | NrTotal | Nr | ExistIndex | (Kein Spaltenname) |
+------------+----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+----+------------+--------------------+
| 1_old      | 1  | Michael Smith   | Michae    | Michae | 1       | 1  | 0          | Michae             |
+------------+----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+----+------------+--------------------+
| 1_old      | 2  | Michael Douglas | Mich_1    | Michae | 2       | 2  | 1          | Mich_1             |
+------------+----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+----+------------+--------------------+
| 1_old      | 3  | Michael Yang    | Mich_3    | Michae | 3       | 3  | 3          | Mich_3             |
+------------+----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+----+------------+--------------------+
| 1_old      | 4  | Testman         | Testma    | Testma | 1       | 1  | 0          | Testma             |
+------------+----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+----+------------+--------------------+
| 1_old      | 5  | Testman1        | Test_1    | Testma | 2       | 2  | 1          | Test_1             |
+------------+----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+----+------------+--------------------+
| 2_new      | 1  | Michael Black   | NULL      | Michae | 4       | 1  | 0          | Mich_4             |
+------------+----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+----+------------+--------------------+
| 2_new      | 2  | Michael White   | NULL      | Michae | 5       | 2  | 0          | Mich_5             |
+------------+----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+----+------------+--------------------+
| 2_new      | 4  | Someone new     | NULL      | Someon | 1       | 1  | 0          | Someon             |
+------------+----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+----+------------+--------------------+
| 2_new      | 3  | Testman2        | NULL      | Testma | 3       | 1  | 0          | Test_2             |
+------------+----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+----+------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: This is amazingly done! I am in awe sir! The only thing this doesn't take into account is if, for example you have  'Mich_2' (Change Michael Yang to 'Mich_3') missing and you run this, there will be a duplicate as it is running off of ROW_NUMBER. Effectively it completely ignores the original increments by reissuing numbers each time it is run

Comment: Amazing... speechless... I was actually trying to accomplish the same thing with your original code, was getting somewhere but not as fast as you have. I cannot send enough thanks for your efforts. Thank you!

Comment: @BrianRamsey Hope you read this: There was a mistake if there is some name completely new... See my update

Comment: Thanks, I used it as a base for building other features so changed that logic anyway. Turned out I was still getting duplicates due to similar company names but different. So increment by results to 2 places not 6.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188300.aspx).

A table design along these lines would work:

```
- Sample table.
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        Id          INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
        FullName    VARCHAR(255),
        ShortName   AS LEFT(FullName, 4) + '_' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(255))
    )
;

-- Add set containing two companies.
INSERT INTO @Sample
    (
        FullName
    )
VALUES
    ('ABC LTD'),
    ('XYZ PLC')
;
```

Returns

```
Id  FullName    ShortName
1   ABC LTD     ABC _1
2   XYZ PLC     XYZ _1
```

The `Id` and `ShortName` columns will be managed by SQL Server.  You only need to add the `FullName`.

**EDIT**

Reworked example using table variable, to make it easier to play along.

Comment: unfortunately this method will do `ABC _1, XYZ _2` , due to current system behavior I would need them to be `ABC _1, XYZ _1`. Also due to current behavior the first entry should always be LEFT 6.

Comment: Ahh I see.  You could combine @RaduGheorghiu solution with a [windowed row count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).